# Angular 4 - Mapping object array to ngModel in template driven from

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I am developing an application in template driven approach. Below is my project structure.

- parent

parent.component.ts

parent.component.html

- child

child.component.ts

child.component.html

child.ts

**child.ts:**

```
export class child {
    public childValue: address[];
}

export class address {
    public state: string;
    public city: string;
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of ValueItem; let i=index">
    <label> {{item.name}}</label>
    <input name="city" [(ngModel)]="address[i].state"/>
</div>
```

When I tried mapping state string of address object to `ngModel`, I am unable to do and its shows an error **"Cannot read property 'state' of undefined".** Is that possible to map an object within an object array to `ngModel`? If so, how can this be done?

Comment: What is ValueItem? Probably its length is shorder that address, so address[i] doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

In short, YES! it is possible to map an object within an object array to ngModel.
You provided this template code.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of ValueItem; let i=index">
   <label> {{item.name}}</label>
   <input name="city" [(ngModel)]="address[i].state"/>
</div>
```

I am assuming that `ValueItem` is of type `address[]` and you have made sure that it contains some data. 
If so, you should be able to access the data via so:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of ValueItem">
   <label> {{item.city}}</label>
   <input name="city" [(ngModel)]="item.state"/>
</div>
```

If we take a look at what is happening. The `*ngFor="Let item of ValueItem;` allows us to iterate through the array and gives us access to the object through `item` which is in this case of type `address`. We know from earlier that `address` has 2 properties `state` and `city`. So to use them we can simply use e.g. `item.state`.

Hope this helped.

Comment: @Anderson - Thanks for your response. But the valueItem is used only for page rendering logic and in no way related to the address state field. What shall I do in this case.

Comment: Could u show me how u define ValueItem in your .ts file ?

Comment: The structure will be like {"valueItem": [{"name": "sam"}, {"name": "tim"}, {"name": "rob"}]}.

Comment: Okey, now i understand. The reason of error "Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" is most likely cause by index reference miss (Happens if ValueItem.length > address.length). I would seriously consider creating singular array of object containing both name and address properties. Before trying to render it in the view.

Comment: Do you mean to say to create value in like this:  {"valueItem": [{"name": "sam", "address": {"city": "xxx", "state": "yyy"}, {"name": "tim",  "address": {"city": "xxx", "state": "yyy"}}, {"name": "rob", "address": {"city": "xxx", "state": "yyy"}]}. But this is not possible in my case as the ValueItem used for rendering logic cannot be related to the model object. Is there any alternate of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the following code is not worked.

```
 <form #myform="ngForm">
    <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let staff of staffs">
         <td><input name="name" [(ngModel)]="staff.name">{{staff.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   </form>
```

the below code worked for me.

```
<form #my2form="ngForm">
   <table>
      <tr *ngFor="let staff of staffs;let i = index">
         <td><input name="staff.{{i}}.name" [(ngModel)]="staff.name">{{staff.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```